# BigCommerce - Grid List of all the brands within your store

Tags: grid, bigcommerce

I was wondering if anyone has any idea how to do the following.

I want to show all the Brands on the site on a grid on a brands page, similar to how products are shown by default but showing brands (the image & name within a panel) that can be clicked through to take users to that brand page.

I had it working for a second but due to thinking it had failed. I changed the Site settings/code and now I cant remember how to get it back to working.

EDIT:

```
<div id="Container">
%%Panel.Header%%
<div class="bannerimg">
    %%Panel.WrapperBanner%%
</div>
<div class="SideBar"><!-- This is desktop only -->
    %%Panel.SideShopByBrand%%
</div>
<div id="Wrapper">
    <div class="ContentHead CatHead Center">
       %%SNIPPET_CategorySortBox%%
        <h1 class="title">%%GLOBAL_PageTitle%%</h1>
        %%Panel.PageBreadcrumb%%
    </div>

    <div class="Content Widest" id="LayoutColumn1">
        %%Panel.PageContent%%
        TEST
        %%Panel.GetInTouch%%
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
%%Panel.Footer%%
</div>
```

The "TEST" string is where I had been trying to add various bits of code to pull in all the brands but most of the time when I add any of that code it breaks the page and nothing loads on a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to just upload an image for the brands (on `/admin/index.php?ToDo=viewBrands` page) and it should automatically appear on `/brands` page.

Comment: I have some images assigned but no such luck. The "Brands" page I made was using the _page.html template theme but I changed it a custom one I made as I thought that would display the way I wanted it. I've updated the question to show my current code.